# Trim the array!

Tags: code-golf, array

Given an integer array and two numbers as input, remove a certain amount of the first and last elements, specified by the numbers. The input can be in any order you want.

You should remove the first *x* elements, where *x* is the first numerical input, and also remove the last *y* elements, where *y* is the second numerical input.

The resulting array is guaranteed to have a length of at least two.

### Examples:

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6] 2 1 -> [3 4 5]
[6 2 4 3 5 1 3] 5 0 -> [1 3]
[1 2] 0 0 -> [1 2]
```

Comment: What, exactly, does it mean to "remove" values from an array—especially to remove them from the end? In languages like C, where an array is just a pointer to the first element and a length, can we just change the length to truncate the array? That's what would *normally* be done in real-world programming, but the challenge is unclear to me.

Comment: @CodyGray Removing values from the array is what it should *look* like, but not necessarily what goes on behind the scenes.

Comment: What do you mean by "look like"? Arrays don't have a *look* – it is *all* behind the scenes!

Comment: @CodyGray It doesn't matter.

Comment: Due to the multitude of answer, you can maybe add a leaderboard snippet to your question?

Comment: @Michthan [Try installing the PPCG userscript](https://github.com/vihanb/PPCG-Design)

Comment: @Okx Nope, that's very buggy, I'd recommend adding a leaderboard.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer It's been working pretty well for me.

Comment: @Okx Try to use TIO provided by the userscript.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Well *that* doesn't work, but the leaderboard does.

Comment: @Okx Also, please stop being lazy...:P...btw the userscript also has unwanted side-effects.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer You do know that there's nothing stopping you from using the [edit](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/128417/edit) button, right? ;)

Comment: @Sanchises I'm not sure if OP wants a leaderboard though.

Comment: Does there need to be a space between the returned values?

Comment: @BruceWayne No, it just needs to be some sort of integer list.

Answer (score 15):

## Haskell, <s>55</s> <s>39</s> <s>33</s> 29 bytes

*Saved 16 bytes thanks to Laikoni*

*Saved 6 more bytes thanks to Laikoni*

*Saved 4 more bytes thanks to Laikoni*

Am sure this could be improved, but as a beginner, gave it my best shot.

```
r=(reverse.).drop
a#b=r b.r a
```

### Usage

```
(5#0) [6,5,4,3,2,1,3]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcxBCoMwFATQvaeYRRcRvsFE4y4nCVkIRiq1Kl/p9dMYEdpZzcBjnv3@CvMcI1vB4RN4D7KUA69bMVohuZQibY7vflpgMawFNp6WAw@MUNBwijQ11JKhzgOoKrg8/a@sYeC6JNtkDSlqfJZn@Xd1fjyf7lxO@/gF)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG and Haskell golfing in particular! The objective is to use as few bytes as possible, so you can for example remove most of the spaces and shorten `xs`.

Comment: @Laikoni Ah, thanks! Edited, can't see myself going any shorter without an anonymous function and using applicative for functions (not sure how that works).

Comment: Looking good now! :) If you change `f x a b` to `f a b x`, you can simply drop the `x`: `f a b=reverse.drop b.reverse.drop a`.

Comment: An additional handy trick from our [Tips for golfing in Haskell](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19255/tips-for-golfing-in-haskell) is to use an infix operator instead of `f`, that is for example `a#b=...` instead of `f a b`. Your usage is then `(5#0)[6,5,4,3,2,1,3]`. Finally you can declare `r=reverse` as auxiliary function and shorten both usages in your main function.

Comment: @Laikoni Wow, interesting infix trick. Thanks again! I was able to shorten it to 33 bytes, but trying to do `a#b=let r=reverse in r.drop b.r.drop a` is 38 bytes. Or are we allowed to have a function declared outside this one?

Comment: From the [Guide to golfing Rules in Haskell](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11924/new-users-guides-to-golfing-rules-in-specific-languages/11935#11935): "you can have auxiliary functions and/or constants defined on separate lines". You can save even more by defining `r y=reverse.drop y`, which again is equal to `r=(reverse.).drop`.

Comment: @Laikoni Thanks for the introduction, very helpful. Just found this site today, but definitely look forward to playing around here some more!

Comment: I'm glad you enjoy the site so far. Using [pointfree.io](http://pointfree.io/) I found one more byte to save: The rules allow also anonymous functions and OP stated that the arguments can be in any order, so `a#b=r b.r a` can be shortened to the anonymous function `(.r).(.).r`. Note that this  changes the calling pattern to `function y x [list]`.

Comment: And to conclude my introduction tour, you can add a link to an online testing environment for the conveninece of others: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcxBCoMwFATQvaeYRRcRvsFE4y4nCVkIRiq1Kl/p9dMYEdpZzcBjnv3@CvMcI1vB4RN4D7KUA69bMVohuZQibY7vflpgMawFNp6WAw@MUNBwijQ11JKhzgOoKrg8/a@sYeC6JNtkDSlqfJZn@Xd1fjyf7lxO@/gF "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, 17 bytes

```
#[[#2+1;;-#3-1]]&
```

**input**

> [{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 2, 1]

Comment: Nice use of `;;`! I managed to tie you with `Drop@##2~Drop~-#&` (if we take the input in a weird order like `1, {1,2,3,4,5,6}, 2`), but no better.

Answer (score 6):

## Octave, 20 bytes

```matlab
@(a,x,y)a(x+1:end-y)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQSNRp0KnUjNRo0Lb0Co1L0W3UvN/Yl6xRrSZgpGCiYKxgqmCoYJxrI6pjoHmfwA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>28</s> 26 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to @Rod*

```python
lambda a,n,m:a[n:len(a)-m]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY3BDoMgEETv/Yo5Ls020WI9kPRLkANNJTWR1SiXfj0Ce5qXN5Pd/@m3ic7hPeXVx8/Xw7NwNN6KWWchrx7R5bAdSPOZsAgs2Z7xZGjGwHgxRte4VwyyY8tD08WVqnYtdU3XaeGusjM3lNuPRRIFutcPSuUL)

Comment: save 6... `lambda a,n,m:a[n:~m]`

Comment: @Aaron this removes one item too much.

Comment: my bad.. It's a common trick I sometimes use, and didn't fully check against the requirements of the challenge..

Comment: @Aaron the slice has a higher operator precedence than the `+` and is therefore applied to `[0]`. You would need brackets: `(a+[0])[n:~m]`.

Comment: yah, realized that later.. I'm trying to make my idea work

Comment: can't you do `lambda a,n,m:a[n:-m]`?

Answer (score 5):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <strike>55</strike> 54 bytes

```cs
using System.Linq;(a,x,y)=>a.Skip(x).Take(a.Count-x-y)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vVBNSwMxEL33Vww9JZANra29tN1LUVEUhAqeY5yW0GyiSbbuUva3x2xYFHoQT32HYZhM3sdIX0jrMNZemT1sWx@w4o/KfC5HI0iQWngPz87unajy5JRrDx9EUBKOVr3Dk1CG0J@n36UeA@1tbeRq6DdWa5RBWeP5HRp0SiZZH1bKhJJBqkP5Y//@xtQVOvGmMX8rYQfrUSSCNayl61Lw7UF9kIbyF3FAIhJJbULRFC2NQ7wzh5tEbzXyV6cCpisg8cGlw/AHm@KN2ZjBjhj8gv@kgBNMGVwxmDGYM7hmsIAuD6aU0uUl9BdZbp4tJP1kZ9ZbSO3kUhb6E/Sak3PNLnddjMUxFl5/Aw)

Uses a `List<int>` as input.

- 1 byte saved thanks to TheLethalCoder!

Comment: I was just about to answer this +1. However, you can save a byte by taking a `List` as input so you can use `Count` instead of `Length`.

Comment: I came up with a solution using `Where` that is only slightly longer than this way that I'm quite happy with as well :)

Comment: You don't need to add `using System.Linq;` to the byte count :)

Comment: @Stefan I need to count every `using` I add in my answer, and the methods `Skip` and `Take` need that `using`.

Comment: hm. okay. On some other challenge I was told that those usings where not necessary.

Comment: @Stefan Note for both of you `using`s are always required if you need to add them in for C#. However, if you use C# Interactive or C# Linqpad or similar you might not need some of them as they are included by default. But then your answer is no longer just C# so you should update the header accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 3 bytes

```
₃
```

[Try it here](http://178.62.56.56:80/neim?code=%F0%9D%95%98%E2%82%83%F0%9D%95%99&input=2%0A%5B1%202%203%204%205%206%5D%0A1)

Thanks to Okx for [encouraging me](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38375386#38375386) to do this...:)

Answer (score 5):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 32 bytes

```java
(l,i,j)->l.subList(i,l.size()-j)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY/BasMwDIbveQodbVBM0za9tCvsUhhspx7HDm7qBHtOYmynkI08e6Y0YWy3GoylX/r0y0beZNo61Zjr56hr1/oIhjTRRW3Fqw5xnyxyiDLq4k/12XvZByHD3Oa6i6V6YWUI8CZ1850A6CYqX8pCwQmmHGBqPryQXCl/BOmc7dl/zeKEgZ4fw/fEDXQXg2WPW6uvUJMNO0evm@r9A6SvAl9sTlDC08gsajQ8PVoRustkwzRSrL8U46nhI9zP/o6c@xBVLdouCkcTo21YKeYF5z@yDNe4wS3muOMIa4SM80fZHbFbonPMcEN0jrB6nCZnYla/zJAM4w8)

If we really restrict to arrays, then it's 53 bytes:

```java
(a,i,j)->java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(a,i,a.length-j)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pc9Pa8MgFADwez7FO0Z4kaZtegkb7NJbKazHsYNLTaozKmo6Qslnz8wfGOxaQZ4@nr/3lOzOMmO5ltfvUbTWuAAy5mgXhKJvzrHel4ntvpSooFLMezgxoR8JgNCBu5pVHI4w3efMxycwa1WfrmeckiCWIEkZ64a4V9AHFmK4G3GFNrLpJTihm@mhazxZ2SPU8DKmDAVKkr3@H49Wxvbn@p3phs9FjCqum3DLJBlhXuXsXHofeEtNF6iNbYLS6SoEszROa7pMr/nP8ptHjlvc4R4LPAwIW4ScEPKEd4jePooF5riLYoGweU6ME0Zn8@cMyTD@Ag)

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 21 bytes

19 bytes of code + `-ap` flags.

```perl
$_="@F[<>..$#F-<>]"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYoxCoAwEAT7e8V6SZuQqJdGDVb5hIpY2IkE/w/xmh1m2Hp/jzTTVSVcvZo9F17LNmfvrSluzge3CfaEX8D7yy2ix4ARgkQ9RUrqoxZBxEBCgfShG34)

Uses `-a` to autosplit the input inside `@F`, then only keep a slice of it according to the other inputs: from index `<>` (second input) to index `$#F-<>` (size of the array minus third input). And `$_` is implicitly printed thanks to `-p` flag.

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), 27 bytes

```
(a,n,m)=>a.slice(n,-m||1/m)
```

A negative second parameter to `slice` stops slicing `m` from the end, however when `m` is zero we have to pass a placeholder (`Infinity` here, although `(a,n,m,o)=>a.slice(n,-m||o)` also works).

Answer (score 4):

### Rust, 29 bytes

```
|n,i,j|&n[i..<[_]>::len(n)-j]
```

Call it as follows:

```
let a = &[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
let f = |n,i,j|&n[i..<[_]>::len(n)-j];
f(a, 2, 1)
```

I had a lot of fun fighting with the borrow checker figuring out what the shortest approach was in order to have it infer the lifetime of a returned slice. Its behavior around closures is somewhat erratic, as it will infer the lifetimes, but only if you do not actually declare the parameter as a reference type. Unfortunately this conflicts with being required to define the argument type in the signature as the n.len method call needs to know the type it's operating on.

Other approaches I tried working around this issue:

```
fn f<T>(n:&[T],i:usize,j:usize)->&[T]{&n[i..n.len()-j]}     // full function, elided lifetimes
let f:for<'a>fn(&'a[_],_,_)->&'a[_]=|n,i,j|&n[i..n.len()-j] // type annotation only for lifetimes. Currently in beta.
|n:&[_],i,j|n[i..n.len()-j].to_vec()                        // returns an owned value
|n,i,j|&(n as&[_])[i..(n as&[_]).len()-j]                   // casts to determine the type
|n,i,j|&(n:&[_])[i..n.len()-j]                              // type ascription (unstable feature)
|n,i,j|{let b:&[_]=n;&b[i..b.len()-j]}                      // re-assignment to declare the type
```

Answer (score 4):

## TIS-100, <s>413</s> 405 Bytes

472 cycles, 5 nodes, 35 lines of code

```
m4,6
@0
MOV 0 ANY
S:MOV UP ACC
JEZ A
MOV ACC ANY
JMP S
A:MOV RIGHT ACC
L:JEZ B
MOV DOWN NIL
SUB 1
JMP L
B:MOV 0 RIGHT
MOV RIGHT NIL
@1
MOV RIGHT LEFT
MOV LEFT DOWN
MOV RIGHT DOWN
MOV DOWN LEFT
@2
MOV UP ACC
MOV UP LEFT
MOV ACC LEFT
@4
MOV 0 RIGHT
MOV UP NIL
S:MOV LEFT ACC
JEZ A
MOV ACC RIGHT
JMP S
A:MOV UP ACC
L:JEZ B
MOV RIGHT NIL
SUB 1
JMP L
B:MOV 0 UP
K:MOV RIGHT ACC
MOV ACC DOWN
JNZ K
@7
MOV UP ANY
```

The m4,6 at the top is not part of the code, but signals the placement of the memory modules.

[image]

Play this level yourself by pasting this into the game:

```
function get_name()
    return "ARRAY TRIMMER"
end
function get_description()
    return { "RECIEVE AN ARRAY FROM IN.A", "RECIEVE TWO VALUES A THEN B FROM IN.T", "REMOVE THE FIRST A TERMS AND LAST B TERMS FROM IN.A", "ARRAYS ARE 0 TERMINATED" }
end

function get_streams()
    input = {}
    trim = {}
    output = {}

  arrayLengths = {}

    a = math.random(1,5) - 3

    b = math.random(1,7) - 4

    arrayLengths[1] = 9+a
    arrayLengths[2] = 9+b
    arrayLengths[3] = 8-a
    arrayLengths[4] = 9-b

    s = 0

    trimIndex = 1

  for i = 1,4 do
      for k = 1,arrayLengths[i] do
          x = math.random(1,999)
      input[k+s] = x
            output[k+s] = x
        end

        input[s + arrayLengths[i] + 1]= 0
        output[s + arrayLengths[i] + 1]= 0

        a = math.random(0,3)
        b = math.random(0,arrayLengths[i]-a)

        trim[trimIndex] = a
        trim[trimIndex+1] = b

        trimIndex = trimIndex + 2

    s = s + arrayLengths[i] + 1
    end

    s = 1
    trimIndex = 1

    for i = 1,4 do

      for i = s,s+trim[trimIndex]-1 do
          output[i]=-99
        end

        for i = s + arrayLengths[i] - trim[trimIndex+1], s + arrayLengths[i]-1 do
      output[i]=-99
        end

  trimIndex = trimIndex +2
  s = s + arrayLengths[i] + 1
    end

    trimmedOut = {}
    for i = 1,39 do
            if(output[i] ~= -99) then
                    table.insert(trimmedOut, output[i])
            end
    end

    return {
        { STREAM_INPUT, "IN.A", 0, input },
        { STREAM_INPUT, "IN.T", 2, trim },
        { STREAM_OUTPUT, "OUT.A", 1, trimmedOut },
    }
end
function get_layout()
    return {
        TILE_COMPUTE,   TILE_COMPUTE,   TILE_COMPUTE,   TILE_COMPUTE,
        TILE_MEMORY,    TILE_COMPUTE,    TILE_MEMORY,   TILE_COMPUTE,
        TILE_COMPUTE,   TILE_COMPUTE,   TILE_COMPUTE,   TILE_COMPUTE,
    }
end
```

So I suppose this also counts as a lua answer...

Comment: You can now [try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZHBboMwEETv@xX7A4lsICHhBLi0hYBBoTRKrmkPkSrl0Pw/HS8poLRII609z94dfLt89wF77POKNas@VlTV76w4sUdqI1d3DSfGUJGdOBETK7GLquGWEoH2@cvrm3Bl5MhUyKf6YNnmJbVdyloOlJRGQwc5QtNhx8V6tlFmz4PvCrlrZo5L6SFo7NFs3ns5XuKmHrCAHgcAJ1NGY7e/iQd6nvneaB54SvJf4q6h3cPf@r1d4hT2xDuKwzGGPfa9Voo9yIcCaAWtoRDaQFtIkXYQGCAgAMCHDdeZ8sABnnjNIW94i4defPXYIoOPWtOaocoV267K9rnhBeXeuFierx@fy9vlSrWeCNb@Dw "TIS – Try It Online") Note: I had to do a clever, and use the top of the code file as one source of input, since TIO currently only provides a single input file.

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 6 bytes

```
QJi-h)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P9ArUzdD8/9/Qy4jrmhDBSMFYwUzBQsFSwXjWAA)

Input is given as 1) number of elements to trim from the start; 2) number of elements to trim from the end; 3) array. Explanation

```
Q   % Implicit input (1). Increment by 1, since MATL indexing is 1-based.
Ji- % Complex 1i minus real input (2). In MATL, the end of the array is given by `1i`.
h   % Concatenate indices to get range-based indexing 1+(1):end-(2).
)   % Index into (implicitly taken) input array. Implicit display.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 3 bytes

```
↓↓_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HbZCCK////v@H/aEMdIx1jHRMdUx2z2P9GAA)

#### Explanation

```
                                               |  1 [1,2,3,4,5,6] 2
  _  -- negate y                               | -1 [1,2,3,4,5,6] 2
 ↓   -- drop y from end (negative argument)    |  [1,2,3,4,5] 2
↓    -- drop x from beginning                  |  [3,4,5]
```

Answer (score 3):

## C#, 62 bytes

```c#
using System.Linq;(l,x,y)=>l.Where((n,i)=>i>=x&i<=l.Count-y-1)
```

Takes a `List<int>` as input and returns an `IEnumerable<int>`.

---

This also works for 64 bytes:

```c#
using System.Linq;(l,x,y)=>l.Skip(x).Reverse().Skip(y).Reverse()
```

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 10 bytes

```
tniQwi-&:)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/vyQvM7A8U1fNSvP//2hDBSMFYwUTBVMFs1guIy5DAA)

### Explanation:

It's a bit long for just 11 bytes, but I'm writing it out in detail, to learn it myself too.

```
---- Input ----
[1 2 3 4 5 6]
2
1
----- Code ----
           % Implicit first input
t          % Duplicate input.
           % Stack: [1 2 3 4 5 6], [1 2 3 4 5 6]
 n         % Number of elements
           % Stack: [1 2 3 4 5 6], 6
  i        % Second input
           % Stack: [1 2 3 4 5 6], 6, 2
   Q       % Increment: [1 2 3 4 5 6], 6, 3
    w      % Swap last two elements
           % Stack: [1 2 3 4 5 6], 3, 6
     i     % Third input
           % Stack: [1 2 3 4 5 6], 3, 6, 1
      -    % Subtract
           % Stack: [1 2 3 4 5 6], 3, 5
       &:  % Range with two input arguments, [3 4 5]
           % Stack: [1 2 3 4 5 6], [3 4 5]
         ) % Use as index
           % Stack: [3 4 5]
           % Implicit display
```

Comment: You forgot about [end-based indexing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/128590/32352) ;)

Comment: (still, have an upvote - I believe this is well golfed and explained considering the method you used)

Comment: Nope, I didn't forget it! I tried, but I didn't figure out how to make it work, (and I really tried). I concluded that it was impossible to subtract something from `J`, when used like this. I suspected I was wrong, I just couldn't figure it out for the life of me... Thanks for linking to your answer, I'm very much a MATL novice...

Comment: Don't worry, I'm also very much learning still - e.g., the order of the inputs to `)` and more notoriously `(` *shiver*...

Comment: @Sanchises Very late comment, but I'm glad it's not just me that finds the input order to `(` confusing. :) I've taken to reciting "ddi" (= "destination, data, indices" from the manual) every time, and still get it wrong sometimes.

Comment: @sundar "diff diff input?" :)  Yeah combined with the 'reversed' way the stack works I still struggle with that.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
Ṗ¡Ḋ⁴¡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9qZWxsef//4bmWwqHhuIrigbTCof///1sxLCAyLCAzLCA0LCA1LCA2Xf8y/zE)

Comment: [Also 5 bytes :)](https://tio.run/##ASsA1P9qZWxsef//4bmr4biK4bmW4oG1wqH///9bMSwyLDMsNCw1LDYsN13/Mv8x)

Comment: @HyperNeutrino I had this version too...but I decided this is more elegant. :)

Answer (score 2):

## Dyalog APL, 16 bytes

```
{(⍵↓⍨⊃⍺)↓⍨-⍺[2]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/7VHbhGqNR71bH7VNftS74lFX86PeXZoQji6QGW0UW/v/v5GCoUIaEBspGCuYKJgqmHGZKhgARcyAIiZAMVOgnDGXAVgMqAoA)

Comment: why was this downvoted?

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>32</s> <s>31</s> 30 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to Rift*

*-1 byte thanks to Jarko Dubbeldam*

```r
pryr::f(n[(1+l):(sum(n|1)-r)])
```

Evaluates to an anonymous function:

```r
function (l, n, r) 
    n[(1 + l):(sum(n|1) - r)]
```

`1+l` is necessary since R has 1-based indexing. `sum(n|1)` is equivalent to `length(n)` but it's a byte shorter.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jRydPp0gzL1rDUDtH00qjuDRXI6/GUFO3SDP2f5qGkY6hlZmOoSZXmoYBkGmkY6D5HwA)

Comment: saving 1 byte with `pryr::f(n[(1+l):(length(n)-r)])`

Comment: Sum(n|1) is shorter than length(n)

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam excellent, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

## C++, <s>96</s> 95 bytes

*Thanks to @Tas for saving a byte!*

```
#import<list>
int f(std::list<int>&l,int x,int y){for(l.resize(l.size()-y);x--;)l.pop_front();}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3dCsMgDIWv51OEDoaCLXR/F9XtVUaxdgi2imawrfTZO2uvlouT5MvhRHlfPpValr0ZvAsorYl4J2ZE6GnErmlWINN@P1i@4nfWD5t6F6itgo7mq9OQGys/TLzLUjBbeecffXAjUibmlD8q@@o0SOMiBt0O25ehNSNlZCKQ6v8hoI4IN5hqDkcOJw5nDhcO11lkd09XQ77VbEMbdwHomm2gyRmM7HKyci8EKRNPUkAhyLz8AA)

## C++ (MinGW), 91 bytes

```
#import<list>
f(std::list<int>&l,int x,int y){for(l.resize(l.size()-y);x--;)l.pop_front();}
```

Comment: Did you mean `#include<list>`? You _could_ shave a byte by having `int f`. Compilers will allow a function to not return, but they'll warn against it

Comment: Yeah, thanks, `int f` will work on most compilers, I'll edit that in. On MinGW, even completely omitting the type of the function works. And yes, `#include<list>` would be a standard-compliant way to include the header, but `#import<list>` should work at least on GCC, MinGW and MSVC, so it should be fine too.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```apl
⌽⎕↓⌽⎕↓⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKMdSPTsfdQ39VHbZASjbypI6n86l6GCkYKxgomCqYIZlxGXIVc6lxlQxAQoZqpgqGDMZcplwAVWBaQNAA)

This takes the array as the first input, followed by the two numbers separately.

#### Explanation

```apl
⎕            from the input array
⎕↓           drop the first input elements
⌽            reverse the array
⎕↓           drop first input elements
⌽            reverse again to go back to the original array
```

Comment: Alternative 7 byte solution: `⎕↓⎕↓⍨-⎕`

Answer (score 2):

## PHP>=7.1, 59 bytes

```php
<?[$a,$b,$e]=$_GET;print_r(array_slice($a,$b,$e?-$e:NULL));
```

[PHP Sandbox Online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/aea18f7a87853a03a8772dd5b7dfaf37540ecd92)

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 60 bytes

```
(()()){({}<{({}<{}>[()])}{}([]){{}({}<>)<>([])}{}<>>[()])}{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X0NDU0NTs1qjutYGQtTaRWtoxmrWVtdqRMdqVgMpoKidpo0diFsLYsMV/P9vzMVlyGXEZcxlwmXKxWUAAA)

Input is in this format:

```
x

a
r
r
a
y

y
```

Where `x` is the number to take from the front, `y` is the number to take from the back, and the array is just however many numbers you want, separated by newlines. Here are my first two (longer) attempts:

```
({}<>)<>{({}<{}>[()])}([])<>({}<><{{}({}<>)<>([])}{}><>){({}<{}>[()])}{}([]){{}({}<>)<>([])}<>{}
{({}<{}>[()])}{}([]){{}({}<>)<>([])}{}<>{({}<{}>[()])}{}([]){{}({}<>)<>([])}<>
```

And here is an explanation:

```
#Two times:
(()()){({}<

    #Remove *n* numbers from the top of the stack
    {({}<{}>[()])}{}

    #Reverse the whole stack
    ([]){{}({}<>)<>([])}{}<>

>)[()]}{}
```

Comment: Nice to see a turing tarpit solution every now and then.

Answer (score 2):

## C++, <s>50</s> <s>48</s> 46 bytes

```c++
#define f(a,x,y)decltype(a)(&a[x],&*a.end()-y)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7LCoMwEEX3@YpBQZIyFmofCw3@SOkiJLEENBGNRRG/PbUptAcuDPcMw8i@z59ShpAq3RiroaECZ1yY0rL1S6@pYDQT9/mB2UEctVWU5QsLqbGynZQGbtzoBy26mvy7l5beDTUx1kMnjKWMrAR2Rq/K8mv5LmsQ6wkLPOMFr3jbKhK3GjdQEJN3YMr4UIEFY1F9@A3xmnSTB87B7EkgqcgW3g)

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 5 bytes

```apl
(⌽↓)/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/7VHbBI1HPXsftU3W1Od61DcVyE8DUtiZ//8bKhgpaIAIYwUTBVMFM00uAyClYQYUMQGKmSoYKhiDxAzAqjQB)

---

Input format is `y x A`

**Explanation**

`/` is Reduce, which inserts the function to the left between each pair of elements of the argument

`(⌽↓)` is a function train equivalent to `{⌽⍺↓⍵}`, which removes the first `⍺` elements of the array `⍵` and then reverses the array. (`⍺` is the left argument and `⍵` is the right argument)

Thus, `(⌽↓)/y x A` is equivalent to `⌽y↓⌽x↓A`, which is what is needed.

Comment: [-1](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/7VHbhEdtkx91zHjUs1ef61HfVKBAGpDCzvz/30jBUEHDUMFIwVjBRMFUwUyTy1TBQEHDDChiAhQzBUoba3IZgMSAqjQB "APL (Dyalog Classic) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 17 bytes

```ruby
->a,b,c{a[b..~c]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5RJ0knuToxOklPry45tvZ/gUJadLShjpGOsY6JjqmOWSyQaRjLBRY2A7JNgBKmOoY6xrFAyiD2PwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 6 bytes

```
oW UsV
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=b1cgVXNW&input=WzEgMiAzIDQgNSA2XQoyCjEKLVE)

```
sVWnUl
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=c1ZXblXK&input=WzYgMiA0IDMgNSAxIDNdCjUKMAotUQ)

```
oW UsV     :Implicit input of array U and integers V=x & W=y
oW         :Remove the last W elements of U, mutating the original
   UsV     :Slice U from 0-based index V
```

```
sVWnUÊ     :Implicit input of array U and integers V=x & W=y
sV         :Slice U from 0-based index V to index
  Wn       :  Subtract W from
    UÊ     :  Length of U
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 30 bytes

```
{a,s,e->a.drop(s).dropLast(e)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY1NCsIwEIX3nmKWGZhKa2sXpQZcCgUXniBgU4IxLUkUpPTsMY3gSmfx5u99M7fRa2WCfBi4C2WYsINr4GiteLUXb5UZOMK8gRhPoUE2wDrlfHsynhNETYKQcfjO4QBhFuSoz7jYXu04MYcpd8J51uMS1ntTvO61YZLpSJ4lKwh2BCVBRbAnqDH1BeLmp71O6yoR0R7pElOV/yPWB9GSfyxLeAM)

Takes `List<Int>` as input and drops from begin and then from end.

Comment: I have not access to `try it online`. Can you add a caller code? how  compile lambda without type definitions in Kotlin? Thanks.

Comment: @mazzy it could probably be a hack, but you can specify types in variable type definition as `val f: (List<Int>, Int, Int) -> List<Int>`

Comment: Got it! Nice. I don't know if this is valid in CodeGolf.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
kb₍B&t;Bk₍
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/PzvpUVOvk1qJtVM2kPH/f7SRjkK0kaGOgpExEJsCsTkQW@ooGBvG6igYxv6PAgA)

Takes input as [x, A, y] where A is the array to trim.

*(-1 byte thanks to @Fatalize.)*

Comment: You can shorten it by 1 byte as such: `kb₍B&t;Bk₍`. `,` does append (see the result of [this partial program](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/PzvpUVOvk479///RRjoK0UaGOgpGxkBsCsTmQGypo2BsGKujYBj7PwoA)), it doesn't act like `∧`. Also do not try to copy things from old (2016-early 2017) Brachylog answers because it was the first version of the language, and programs are not retrocompatible (in particular, `,` in Brachylog v1 is now `∧` in Brachylog v2)

Comment: @Fatalize Thanks, updated. So `,` did append in the previous version, but it just didn't matter in this case because there was a `t` after it anyway - lucky coincidence. And yeah, I realized the version differences after I posted this, I was still figuring things out and bumbling around at this stage. :)

Answer (score 2):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 10 bytes

```
{(-z)_y_x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/v1pDt0ozvjK@ojbaUMFIwVjBRMFUwczayNow9v9/AA)

Port of my q/kdb+ answer...

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
F¦}sF¨
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f7dCy2mK3Qyv@/zfiijbUMdIx1jHRMY3lMgQA)

```
F }    # For 0 .. number of elements to remove from front
 ¦     #   Remove the first element
   s   # Get the next input
    F  # For 0 .. number of elements to remove from back
     ¨ #   Remove the last element
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 5 bytes

```
>E<QE
```

[Try it here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3CE%3EQE&input=%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4%2C+5%2C+6%5D%0A1%0A2&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4%2C+5%2C+6%5D%0A1%0A2%0A%5B6%2C+2%2C+4%2C+3%2C+5%2C+1%2C+3%5D%0A0%0A5%0A%5B1%2C+2%5D%0A0%0A0&debug=0&input_size=3)

Takes the arguments in the opposite order. `<` and `>` in Pyth trim based on argument order. For example, `<Q5` will trim off all values in the input after the fifth one.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 82 bytes

```java
a->n->m->{int l=a.length-m-n,r[]=new int[l];System.arraycopy(a,n,r,0,l);return r;}
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##pZA9a8MwEIZ3/4obbZBFnK9FjaFLoUOnjMGD6qipUvkk5HOKMf7trpLYDbSdGtBwuvf08JyO8iRT6xQe9x@Drpz1BMfQ4w1pwx@9l20tol/BW4MlaYv8aSxEVBpZ1/AiNXYRQE2SdAlT/KCRdgW73Z@R1EH5vzqX0TzPoYQNDDLNMc2rNO9CH8xGcqPwQO9plSLzu2KD6vPyxBRi29akKi7P1qV1bSxZmGEzZhLhFTUewYt@EMEvHNe8mqA4mp6s3kMV7OMteY2HXQEyOW8CMGJtQ9yFiAzG14/hZK/Dccmlc6aNJ5miy9icLdiSrdi6T8Z0PhVZkiTi/@x1YC8DfcUytvimr6Zidh89mPc31A9mH/XDFw)

Alternative with same (**82**) byte-count using a loop:

```java
(a,n,m)->{int l=a.length-m,r[]=new int[l-n],i=0;for(;n<l;r[i++]=a[n++]);return r;}
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##nY/NboMwEITvPMUejbJY@b@4VOoDNJccEQeXOKmpWZAxqSLEs9MFWvUeyfLI69E3s6W@66RuDJWXr9FWTe0DlDyTXbBOvnmvH62KCqfbFt61pT4CsBSMv@rCwGl6zoMsh0IsqnEaAC1SxYo9Q8RXG3SwBZyAIIVRaCSs4uS1n2wu1dIZuoXPpEKf5SmZ75nrEsrRpmt1rb1Q9OKUz@xqlac6I5ZYeRM6T@DVME5JfJruw3HOb9y9theouLo4B2/pNjWMl97nRxtMJesuyIa/giOxbCxDvZgFyUL8Vcn7DW5xh3s84HFA2CJs4nje7wnWkVl7ph1wgzumHRDWz9O4GTPW/4whGsYf)

**Explanation:**

```java
a->n->m->{                      // Method with integer-array and two integer parameters and integer-array return-type
  int l=a.length-m-n,           //  Length of the array minus the two integers
      r[]=new int[l];           //  Result integer-array
  System.arraycopy(a,n,r,0,l);  //  Java built-in to copy part of an array to another array
  return r;                     //  Return result-String
}                               // End of method
```

[`System.arraycopy`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/system_arraycopy.htm):

> `arraycopy(Object src, int srcPos, Object dest, int destPos, int length)`:
>
> The `java.lang.System.arraycopy()` method copies an array from the specified source array, beginning at the specified position, to the specified position of the destination array. A subsequence of array components are copied from the source array referenced by `src` to the destination array referenced by `dest`. The number of components copied is equal to the `length` argument.
>
> The components at positions `srcPos` through `srcPos + length - 1` in the source array are copied into positions `destPos` through `destPos + length - 1`, respectively, of the destination array.

Comment: Can you save bytes by not using currying?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder No, in this case not. `(a,n,m)->` has the same byte-count as `a->n->m->`. Although you're right I could have just used a regular call instead of currying. I'm kinda used of using currying when I have two (or more) parameters.. I've already made the mistake of using currying when I have four parameters a few times..

Comment: Ahh you're right I miscounted the bytes and I've done that as well currying is definitely a go to now!

Comment: No TIO link? --

Comment: @totallyhuman It did contain a TIO link for the first solution, but I've added a TIO-link for the alternative solution as well now.

Comment: Sorry, can't let that pass. I posted [my own answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/128669/16236) because... there's a built-in (ok, not exactly, but nearly)! :o

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Nice, that's a lot shorter!

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 8 bytes

```
{_,@-<>}
```

Anonymous block that takes the inputs from the stack in the order *x*, *y*, array, and replaces them by the output array.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1vxGXIFW1ooGBkoGBsoGBioGBqoGBmEPu/Ol7HQdfGrvZ/XcF/AA)

#### Explanation

Consider inputs `2`, `1`, `[10 20 30 40 50 60]`.

```
{      }    e# Block
            e# STACK: 2, 1, [10 20 30 40 50 60]
 _          e# Duplicate
            e# STACK: 2, 1, [10 20 30 40 50 60], [10 20 30 40 50 60]
  ,         e# Length
            e# STACK: 2, 1, [10 20 30 40 50 60], 6
   @        e# Rotate
            e# STACK: 2, [10 20 30 40 50 60], 6, 1
    -       e# Subtract
            e# STACK: 2, [10 20 30 40 50 60], 5
     <      e# Slice before
            e# STACK: 2, [10 20 30 40 50]
      >     e# Slice after
            e# STACK: [30 40 50]
```

Comment: Good point, then just for fun, here is an alternative 8-byte solution :) https://tio.run/##S85KzP1vxGXIFW1ooGBkoGBsoGBioGBqoGBmEPu/Olg7ps7GrvZ/XcF/AA

Answer (score 1):

## tcl, 19

```
lrange $L $x end-$y
```

where `L` is the array.

## [demo](http://rextester.com/TBJ29608)

Answer (score 1):

## q/kdb, 12 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{(0-z)_y _x}
```

**Example:**

```
q){(0-z)_y _x}[1 2 3 4 5 6;2;1]
3 4 5
q){(0-z)_y _x}[6 2 4 3 5 1 3;5;0]
1 3
q){(0-z)_y _x}[1 2;0;0]
1 2
```

**Explanation:**

```
{          } / lambda function
          x  / input array
       y _   / drop y elements from .. (takes from start)
 (0-z)       / negative z ()
      _      / drop -z elements from ... (takes from end)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Racket, 33 bytes

```
(λ(a i j)(drop-right(drop a i)j))
```

It can be called like so:

```
((λ(a i j)(drop-right(drop a i)j)) '(1 2 3 4 5 6) 2 1)
```

Comment: Can I have a link to the language's website?

Comment: @Okx https://racket-lang.org/

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 4 bytes

```
<E>E
```

[Demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3CE%3EE&input=2%0A1%0A%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4%2C+5%2C+6%5D&debug=0)

Put the list last.

Answer (score 1):

## Kona/K4, 12 bytes

```
{x _(-y)_ z}
```

Usage:

```
   {x _(-y)_ z}[2;1;"hello world"]
"llo worl"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 16 bytes

The compiler instruction:

```c
-DX(a,x,y)=(a+x)
```

As most would know, an array in C is just a known length and a pointer to the beginning of an array. Thus, we get an array with `x` members removed from the left and `y` members removed from the right by just moving the pointer to the array by `+x`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYs9C4MwFEVn/RUPB0naF6gfHaRkELp16CpIh0eKQWilkEgt4l/va6rbPffeY5Q1hpmf1A9CxnMc9YOHur2BhjlDyBEKhBLhuJy2bUchkG5EjRAOmfz3naD2EBwNOaQpUJutUGyQr1DKOIpeo3ciuV6SoC38Nd2DrGPl/F3bYawqVm9W50YQTviRWtB@kj8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
‘ṫṚ¥ƒ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw4yHO1c/3Dnr0NJjk/4fXu6g/6hpTeT//9HRhjoKRjoKxjoKJjoKpjoKZrE6CtFAAcNYECPaDCxrAlYAlAUqNgaJA5kGEAUg7SCGAVgEAA)

Takes `[x, y]` on the left and the list on the right. Ties the existing Jelly answer, but I'm posting it anyways because:

- it doesn't use full-program I/O
- it feels like it *should* be four bytes

```
‘        Increment x and y.
    ƒ    With the list as the initial value of the accumulator, reduce [x, y] by:
 ṫ       remove the first (right - 1) elements from the accumulator,
  Ṛ¥     then reverse it.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jellyfish](https://github.com/iatorm/jellyfish), 19 bytes

```
p
vvj
 -0
 j
 0
j
0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyalMyyzO@P@/gKusLItLQdeASwFIGXBlcRn8/2/MFW2qYKZgrmChYKlgEMtlCAA)

Takes input as

```
y
array
x
```

via STDIN.

This program translates to:

```
p    (v   (j         (0),v   (-    (0,j         (0)),j         (0)))
print(drop(eval_input(0),drop(minus(0,eval_input(0)),eval_input(0)))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 18 bytes

```julia
a*b*c=a[1+b:end-c]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY3BDoMgEETvfMUcgVIiKh6a0B8hHNDaxMZgo9ukf083dm5v3mbn9VmX7L61Zj3qKeToLuNtLo/rlCrNBx0IiEJGhxYdengMyaA1cFBcD1z3LDxzx8IbNKfge8bmj0k8tx2EpeD8KcB570uhtUhCuENLstYqJXi6/gA)

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 32 bytes

```
=OFFSET(A1,B1,,COUNT(A:A)-B1-C1)
```

[Link the Spreadsheet](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AkqhtBc2XEHJnCUTz0glFcSW7LAt?e=rZMang)

The array is entered in column A starting at A1.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
N"i
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJOXCJpIiwiIiwiMlxuMVxuWzEsMiwzLDQsNSw2XSJd)

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 49 bytes, `int`s only

```go
func f(t[]int,x,y int)[]int{return t[x:len(t)-y]}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BzoLE5OzE9FSF3MTMPK7M3IL8ohI9pbTcEqWlpSVpuhY3DdNK85IV0jRKomMz80p0KnQqFYC0JphXXZRaUlqUp1ASXWGVk5qnUaKpWxlbC9VYBNYIMlZDU6GaK6AIqCEnTyNNA6LVUMdIx1jHRMdUx6wWyDTU1MRQYgYUNwEqMtUx1DGuBVIGWBQBzanVMQBLQW1esABCAwA)

## [Go](https://go.dev), 52 bytes, generic

```go
func f[T any](t[]T,x,y int)[]T{return t[x:len(t)-y]}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BzoLE5OzE9FSF3MTMPK7M3IL8ohI9pbTcEqWlpSVpuhY3TdJK85IV0qJDFBLzKmM1SqJjQ3QqdCoVMvNKNIHs6qLUktKiPIWS6AqrnNQ8jRJN3crYWqjeRrBekMkamgrVXAFFQE05eRpp0UA6ViM6FkhVG-oY6RjrmOiY6pjVApmGmprY1ZkBJU2AKk11DHWMa4GUAS6VQBNrdQzA8lCHLFgAoQE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$5\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 4.12 bytes

```
ZxsZy
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhZLoyqKoyohbKjQgo1GXNGGOkY6xjomOqY6ZrFchhAJAA)

Takes `x` then the array then `y`

##### Explanation

```python
Zx     # Remove the first x elements from the array
  s    # Swap so y is now on the top of the stack
   Zy  # Remove the last y elements from the array
       # Implicit output
```

Comment: Why is there no slice builtin -.-

Comment: @Jacob I forgot to add that... :(

Answer (score 1):

## [Elm](https://elm-lang.org/), 44 bytes

```hs
h x=List.reverse<<List.drop x
f x y=h y<<h x
```

[Try it on Ellie](https://ellie-app.com/kQKTjRL6JB9a1)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <strike>8</strike> 7 bytes

```
sVUl -W
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/vzgsNEdBN/z//2gzBSMFEwVjBVMFQwXjWCBlAAA)

Saved a byte thanks to ETHproductions

Comment: Hmm, do you need the comma?

Comment: @ETHproductions A bit late, but the comma isn't needed; I keep forgetting that trick. Thanks!

Comment: [6 bytes](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=c1ZXblVs&input=WzYgMiA0IDMgNSAxIDNdIDUgMA==)

Answer (score 0):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
ÀñdñGÀñd
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v//3DD4Y0phze6g@n//824jLhMuIy5TLkM/5v@NwAA)

One byte saved thanks to Erik the golfer!

Comment: You don't need last `ñ`.

Comment: The first four bytes can become `Àd`.

Comment: @kritixilithos Unfortunately, that doesn't work for two reasons. 1) `d` by itself doesn't work. You'd need `dd` and 2) That doesn't work if the first input is 0.

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 28 bytes

```
#(subvec % %2(-(count %)%3))
```

Well there is the built-in.

Answer (score 0):

## [NewStack](http://ttps://github.com/LyamBoylan/NewStack/), 5 bytes

```
ᵢqᵢpᵢ
```

The symmetry is an amazing coincidence

### The breakdown:

```
ᵢ      Append an input (the array).
 qᵢ    Pop off an input's amount off the bottom.
   pᵢ  Pop off an input's amount off the top.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [F#](http://fsharp.org/), 39 bytes

```fs
let f(i:int[])s e=i.[s..(i.Length-1-e)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvWzc3Py///Pye1RCFNI9MqM68kOlazWCHVNlMvulhPTyNTzyc1L70kQ9dQN1Uz9n9BEVBFWp6CkqqjkoJGWnSNoZ6eoUFNrIKhgrHmfwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), <s>22</s> 21 bytes

```
1-<1-[v$_R][v<$_R]v=;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@//fUNfGUDe6TCU@KDa6zAZEldla////P9pQR8FIR8FYR8FER8FUR8Es9r/Rf0MA)

Answer (score 0):

### LOGO, 33 bytes

```
[cascade ?2 "bf cascade ?3 "bl ?]
```

Try it on FMSLogo.

This is a `template-list` in LOGO, which is the equivalent of lambda (anonymous) function in many other languages.

Where:

- `cascade` outputs the result of applying a template repeatedly, in this case is `?2` times `bf` and `?3` times `bl`.
- `bf` and `bl` stands for `ButFirst` and `ButLast` respectively.
- `?` is used to access parameters. So `?2` is the second parameter, `?3` is the third parameter, etc.

Test:

```
show apply [cascade ?2 "bf cascade ?3 "bl ?] [[1 2 3 4 5 6] 2 1]
```

print `[3 4 5]`.

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure, 26 bytes

```
#(drop %2(drop-last %3 %))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 18 bytes

```
{@^a[$^x..^*-$^y]}
```

`@^a` is the input array (first parameter), `$^x` is the number of elements to remove from the front (second parameter), and `$^y` is the number of elements to remove from the end (third parameter).

`$^x ..^ *-$^y` is a slicing subscript that selects a range of elements from the one with index `$^x` until one prior to the one with index `*-$^y` (`*` meaning "the length of the array" in a subscript context).

Answer (score 0):

## C++, 81 bytes

```
#include<vector>
int f(std::vector<int>&v,int x,int y){v={v.begin()+x,v.end()-y};}
```

Not as short as [this use of a macro](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/128488/42561).

`std::vector` provides random access, and we simply create a new `vector` from the start point `v.begin()` + `x`, to the new end point `v.end()` - `y` elements.

Uses the iterator overload `v.begin()` and `v.end()` since it's the same length as the pointer one `&v[0]` and `&*(v.end())`, but more readable.

Function doesn't return an `int` like it promises, which is only a compiler warning.

Answer (score 0):

## [8th](http://8th-dev.com/), 33 bytes

**Code**

This code leaves resulting array on TOS

```
( a:rev swap -1 a:slice ) 2 times
```

**Usage**

```
ok> 2 1 [1,2,3,4,5] ( a:rev swap -1 a:slice ) 2 times .
[3,4]
ok> 5 0 [6,2,4,3,5,1,3] ( a:rev swap -1 a:slice ) 2 times .
[1,3]
ok> 
ok> 0 0 [1,2] ( a:rev swap -1 a:slice ) 2 times .
[1,2]
ok>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, 41 bytes

```
(lambda(a x y)(subseq a x(-(length a)y)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DchLDoAgEATRq/TOnoUL/N1nQKIkSFA00dMju3rlYii5Ml8hObAy6mFXpeLFJyyPLf5EE3tGn7Z7h8onIrWjwYARE2Ys0tK0@QM)

Answer (score 0):

## J, 17 bytes

```
(-@{:@[}.{.@[}.])
```

Usage:

```
   2 1 (-@{:@[}.{.@[}.]) 11 12 13 14 15 16
13 14 15
```

Answer (score 0):

## C++, 50 bytes

```c++
[](auto&v,int x,int y){v={v.begin()+x,v.end()-y};}
```

Just construct a new container from the existing one.  This requires `v` to be of a type with random-access iterators and constructible from an iterator pair - `std::vector` is ideally suited.

### Demo

```c++
auto const trim =
    [](auto&v,int x,int y){v={v.begin()+x,v.end()-y};}
    ;

#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 4) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " X Y ELE...";
        return 1;
    }

    auto const x = std::atoi(argv[1]);
    auto const y = std::atoi(argv[2]);
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.reserve(argc - 3);
    for (int i = 3;  i < argc;  ++i)
        v.push_back(std::atoi(argv[i]));

    auto const print_vector = [](auto v){for(auto i:v)std::cout<<i<<" ";std::cout<<'\n';};

    print_vector(v);
    trim(v, x, y);
    print_vector(v);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 52 bytes

```scala
def f(a:Seq[Int],c:Int,d:Int)=a.dropRight(d).drop(c)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYw7D8IwDIR3fkVGW7JQ09dQiYGRgaWMiCHkAamqNLQZkBC/PZhuiOXOZ3@@RatR5ek6WJ3EUfkg7DPZYBaxj/GVjXXCgepO9nE@hHQh3bGR@Sru1NbMU@z97Z7A4BpAY46zD2kM4IDfQFJJFdXUUIs8SsTNL9DytmakIUkVshV/CHcgFevhnT8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 94 bytes

```lua
n,s=loadstring('return{},'..p[1])()for x=1,#s do n[#n+1]=x>0+p[2]and#s>=x+p[3]and s[x]or _ end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYxBCsMgEAC/sjSHKBGJ6dl8RCTYmJZCWEUNCMG3by3MZQ4z5@UogoZbStkIRdZncD6X9MUPG9NRroR3E6OU0SjLGX@HBFUrMWTwAdAMOCmr6zpP0SzWoR/yqmuX518gm2p7scGBnmK/Flbc6zzkHnB3haGAR4dzoluJpdFM8w8)

If I used something that I couldn't please tell me.

#### Explanation

```lua
p = {...} -- (Header) It gets the 3 arguments (the list and the 2 numbers and stores in a table)


n,s=loadstring('return{},'..p[1])() -- is the same as (i) and (ii):
 (i) n = {} -- initializes an empty table
(ii) s = loadstring('return '..p[1])() -- makes the string '{1,2,3}' become a table with 3 elements (1, 2 and 3)

for x=1,#s do -- from 1 to the number of elements in s, repeat:
  n[#n+1] = x>0+p[2] and #s>=x+p[3] and s[x] or _
  n[#n+1]   -- append to n
              0+p[2]   -- convert "2" to the number 2
            x>0+p[2] and #s>=x+p[3]   -- if we're past the start limit and before the end limit
                                    and s[x]   -- then the element to be appended is the one with index x of the original list
                                             or _   -- else append nil (the same as doing nothing)
end


print(table.concat(n, ", ")) -- (Footer) print the elements of n separated by commas
```

I used _ as nil just to be a little bit more clear (although this is not the point of these answers hahah). I could've used any variable that wasn't previously declared. `_` doesn't have anything special in Lua.
And the comparisons are really messy because I tried to organize the math in a way that special characters would help me to use less space. `... and a>#b` uses 1 more byte than `... and#b>a`.

If you have any questions ask and I'll try to answer them.

Answer (score 0):

## [Recursiva](https://github.com/officialaimm/recursiva), 7 bytes

```
Zba-Lac
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pNLi0qzixL/P8/KilR1ycx@f//aDMdIx0THWMdUx1DHeNYBVMFAwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 19 bytes

```
[ head* swap tail ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQnVqUl5qjUJxaWJqal5xarFBQlFpSUllQlJlXomDNxWWkUK1gqGCkYKxgomCqYKZQq2D4P1ohIzUxRUuhuDyxQKEkMTNHIfZ/cmJOjoLefwA)

Takes input as `x sequence y`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 31 bytes

```
$[a,x,y][slice a x(size a)-y+1]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?wuEFgt)

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 21 bytes

```sh
<<<${@:2+$1:-1-$@[#]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn938bGRqXawcpIW8XQStdQV8UhWjm29n8tV5qCkYIhEBsrmCiYKpgpGAJFQLQRkG8MZBkCSQOgmAFYlcF/AA)

Input format: `x` `<array>` `y`

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ỵẓ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWyx7u3vpw1-QlxUnJxVChBduMuKINdRSMdBSMdRRMdBRMdRTMYrkMIbIA)

Input in the order \$a, l, b\$, where \$a\$ is the number of items to remove from the front, \$b\$ is the number of items to remove from the back, and \$l\$ is the list.

##### Explanation

```python
ỵẓ  # Implicit input
ỵ   # Remove from front
 ẓ  # Remove from back
    # Implicit output
```